# Determining the focal length of a convex lens (no-parallax method)

Tags: optics, experimental-physics, lenses

This is about the experiment where we determine the focal length of a convex lens using the graphical method,(the no parallax method).
In the situation where the image moves opposite to the direction that I move my eye,do I have to move the observation pin towards my eye or away from my eye?

Comment: What do you mean by “graphical method”?

Comment: @Farcher finding the focal length by drawing a graph for different u and v values we obtain experimentally

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the method of no-parallax you need to have the image of the object pin in the same position (position of no parallax) as the observation pin.

I hope that the diagram below is self explanatory?

[image]

Comment: So I should move the pin towards my eye right?